# How to change the style of a TW3HeaderControl's text in Smart Mobile Studio 2.2.4....?

Tags: css, smart-mobile-studio

SMS 2.2.4.....

using the following CSS:

```
.lblHeader{
  color: #005CB9;
}
```

If I drop a TW3Label on the form and set its StyleClass = lblHeader';

it works fine.

however, if I try to change the Style class of the one on the headercontrol, it doesn't work.

```
W3HeaderControl1.Title.StyleClass:= 'lblHeader';
```

I have tried it in both the *InitializeForm* and *InitializeObjects* methods and still nothing! What is the trick? :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to warleyalex from the SMS community forum, the answer is:

Runtime:

```
w3_setStyle(W3HeaderControl1.Handle.childNodes[0], 'color', '#005CB9');
```

design-time

```
.TW3HeaderControl fieldset{
  color: #005CB9 !important;
}
```